# EF4 Insert in VB and return ID of inserted row like ExecuteScalar() does

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Please could someone show me how to do an insert with EF4 VB and also how to return the ID of the inserted row?

This is what I have got for edit and it works.. I have seen some very confusing ways of doing selects and edits and have found that i'm most comfortable keeping it written nice like this so that I can go back and understand what I have done... :)

> ```
>    Using db As New productionEntities
>         Dim edit = (From ordEdit In db.orders Where ordEdit.order_id = 56149 Select ordEdit).First
>         edit.ExportedToOW = 0
>         db.SaveChanges()
>     End Using
> ```

I want to insert a new order with an order_id and value for ExportedToOW and get the order_id back which is auto generated by the DB...

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following help:

```
Using db As New productionEntities

    Dim newOrder As New Order
    newOrder.ExportedToOW = 123
    db.Orders.AddObject(newOrder)
    db.SaveChanges()

    ' Get the newly generated Id.
    dim newKey as Integer = newOrder.order_id

End Using
```

This works because when a field is set up as an autonumber field then EF will update the entity with the generated value when a SaveChanges() is performed.